# Revoking SELECT from database owner in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, privileges

I am trying to revoke `SELECT` from the user which is the database owner. 
I have logged in as the `database_owner` into psql.

And then run the following command

```
REVOKE SELECT ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA "some_schema" FROM database_owner;
```

This command run with giving `REVOKE` as its output.

However at the end, the user is still able to `SELECT` from tables in the schema. Is it possible to revoke this privilege from database owner?

Comment: you can try row level security with force I suppose?..

Comment: You can't revoke privileges from the database owner. Check this https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77725/revoke-delete-from-table-for-database-owner

Comment: btw database owner cant read table if not owner or granted - no?..

Comment: Change the owner.